# C++ code for producing core-file just like gdb >> gcore does

Tags: c++, gdb, memory-dump, core-file, gcore

Does anyone know any C++ libraries or code that will help me to produce a core-file of a process with certain PID just like the one that is produced using gdb using the gcore command. I am working on linux.

Answer (score 1):

There is google user-space [coredumper](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-coredumper/).